# Error validation is incremented and duplicated

Tags: go, beego

Somehow my error validations are duplicated when I use valid global variable like below

```
var (
    valid validation.Validation
)

func validationInit() validation.Validation {
    valid := validation.Validation{}
    return valid
}
```

But when I move `valid := validation.Validation{}` to my model function it works fine without any duplicates like below:

```
func AddClub(name string) (id int64, error []*validation.ValidationError) {
    club := Club{Name: name}
    valid := validation.Validation{}
```

How am I able to not duplicate this valid across each function but reuse variable without results being incremented and duplicated?

Comment: Are you aware that `valid := validation...` shadows the `var` declaration of `valid`?

Comment: @topskip Yes I do. I just put it there to test but when I take that out, it duplicates and increments again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `validationInit()` func returns a `validation.Validation` *value* and not a *pointer* to it, you cannot return the same global variable from multiple functions or from multiple invocations of the same function.

If you really want this, you have to return a pointer to the global variable, else a copy of the value of the global variable will be returned.

Example:

```
var valid validation.Validation

func someFunc() *valid.Validation {
    // You can access the global variable valid here, you can also modify it
    return &valid
}
```

But this is most likely not what you want. This would not allow you to have 2 different `validation.Validation` values exist at the same time returned by your functions.

I suggest you to leave out the global variable, and just create a new `validation.Validation` value each time it is needed and return that new value (either by value or a pointer to it).